# Does the turboprop engine torque get transferred to the engine mount and ultimately aircraft when engine is active?

Tags: torque, moments, engines

When the turboprop engine is active, the propeller shaft rotates and causes the propeller to rotate as well, which in turn generates thrust. The propeller shaft rotates because of the torque (or twisting moment) created by the turbines of the engine and then which is conveyed to the propeller shaft. My question is that if I am trying to conduct a FEA analysis for the mount at which this engine is attached, should I also apply this torque on it or not?
I was thinking that I shouldn't apply any kind of torque at this engine mount since I don't think that engine itself is rotating at all because of any twisting moment, but it is recommended that the torque should always be taken into account while conducting such analysis. Moreover, I believe that there exists some bearings somewhere inside the engine which makes the engine mount to not take any kind of torque generated by the engine.

Comment: The simplest rotation machine is the house fan, does its stand move while the fan is at its top speed? However, if the base is too small to handle the drag it created, the fan will be falling forward. This observation tells us a fact - the engine mount (base) has nothing to do with the torque but the thrust it causes.

Comment: @r13 the fan base is always made with enough mass. Just hold one in your hand and see if there is a reaction. If not try it with an electric drill with a big bit and see if your wrists notice a reaction force when you jam the bit…

Comment: @SolarMike You confuse me with mass while I was talking torque. Will a handheld cooling fan **rotate** on my hand? We feel differently though.

Comment: @r13 the mass and torque are linked… or don’t you get that? If the fan base does not have enough mass or the mass is not sufficiently distant then the fan will be unstable. Put a drill bit in a drill and clamp the drill bit in a vice. Take good hold of the drill and pull the trigger. Done it often to test if the motor develops full power. Note the reaction force.

Comment: @SolarMike You keep talking about mass, weight, and stability. What is to keep the lightweight fan housing to rotate if the fan motor produced torque (to rotate the blades) is acting on it? This is a household fan that sits on the floor and can be lifted by hand during operation.

Comment: This subject is taking on the urban legend status of sailing directly downwind faster than the wind. Some of it does. How much of it does depends on design choices and the operating conditions.

Comment: @PhilSweet Sorry, but this is a perfectly straightforward question about dynamics and in fact every trainee *pilot* (not just aircraft designers) is taught the answer - for the good reason that *not* knowing the answer is a good way to crash the aircraft when taking off!

Comment: @alephzero Yes, its a straight forward question. The answer is no, none of the shaft torque is transferred to the engine mounts, just like none of the drive shaft torque is transferred to the engine mounts in an ICE. But inevitably, there are other torques that are transferred. Computing them accurately is tricky; and the total is somewhat negotiable from an engineering prospective.

Answer (score 3):

For every action there is an equal, but opposite, reaction.

Never found a case that this is not true.

Torque reaction on the P51 even caused uneven tire wear:
https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2007/august/pilot/north-american-aviation-p-51d-mustang

So, if you open the bonnet or hood of a car and run the engine with it in neutral, then blip the throttle you will see the engine try to rotate in the opposite direction to that which it runs. Yet another example and it’s not connected to the output…

Comment: The Newton's third law always holds. The problem is I couldn't understand if there physical connection between the turbines (or propeller shaft) and the engine casing (to which the mount is attached). If there is no physical connection, then I couldn't think of any reason why the engine casing or the mount will also be experiencing the torque or twisting moment. Moreover, I don't know the torque (if) experienced by the engine casing and mount would be equal to what the propeller shaft or turbine is experiencing.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq Since the engine housing does not rotate there must be no net torque on the engine. We know the engine applies torque to the propeller. So where do you suppose the counter-torque is, which makes it zero net? Now, to my untrained eye I wouldn't have thought that torque was *significant*, but maybe it is....

Comment: The torque (which balances the drag of the prop blades going around the circle) is transmitted to the prop by the turbine. Specifically the rotating parts of it.The reaction force would be in the turbine stator blades.

Comment: @user253751, well I was thinking that the torque produced at the turbine and hence onto the propeller shaft was being cancelled out by the airflow around the turbine blades and not by the engine itself. The reason being, as I already mentioned, there is no physical connection between the turbine blades (or the propeller shaft) with the engine.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq Oh, hmm, it is possible.

Comment: @user253751, maybe since the airflow around the turbine is also in contact with the engine casing, then the airflow cancels out the torque on the shaft, and the engine casing then cancels out this torque produced by the airflow, and the mount then cancels out the torque produced by the engine casing.

Comment: A turbine consists of rotors and stators, doesn't it? I'd expect there to be torque on the stators

Comment: @user253751, doesn't matter if the torque is on the stator or rotor, the point is that the turbine is causing the torque on the propeller shaft and because of this the propeller is rotating. Our topic of question was what cancels out this torque on the turbine. Maybe the airflow around these turbine blades produces a torque in the opposite direction to cancel it out, which in turn produces a torque on the engine casing since the airflow is kinda in connection with the engine casing as well. Or maybe torque doesn't get cancelled out, and the propeller shaft undergoes a rotational acceleration.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq A stator is a part which is attached to the housing. If there is torque on the stators it's transferred to the housing

Comment: @user253751, then there should exist a bearing connection between the stator and the propeller shaft. Because it doesn't make any sense to put the stators (connected to the engine casing) with the propeller shaft since they will make the whole engine to rotate. Engine designers would never do that I guess lol I believe the torque is transferred from the rotors.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq so how does a torque converter work in an automatic, prior to it reaching lock-up of course? You might need to do some reading or even do that drill test…

Comment: @Rameez - I think it is both. Some of the torque is left behind in the angular momentum - vorticity of air exiting. Some is transferred to the aircraft surfaces outside the engine by the engine mount. This must be by the net torque on stators in the compressor and turbine (which is opposite sign), I don't think there's anything else.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq "doesn't matter if the torque is on the stator or rotor". It totally matters. The shaft is isolated by bearings. It *can't* exert a torque on the mounts, That is what the bearings are for - so it can't. Shaft torque does not get transmitted to the mounts, but stator torque and gearbox frame torque does. Gearbox torque should be about 15 times as big as stator torque - perhaps in the opposite direction.

Comment: @PhilSweet, the stator torque getting transferred to the engine casing (and hence to the mount) is equal but opposite to what the propeller shaft is experiencing? Plus, how can I calculate the gearbox frame torque? Does the gearbox frame has a physical connection to the engine casing (as like the stators)?

Comment: It depends on the design. The stator torque can be anything the designer wants it to be. But the total angular momentum has to balance out, so shaft torque, stator torque, and swirl are related. Gearbox torque is straight forward. All you need is the gear reduction ratio and then perform a static balance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed it creates a reaction torque equal and in opposite direction in the frame of the airplane. All the engine mounts have diagonal braces designed to transfer the propeller's torque to the wing or mount.

It is immediately noticeable in a helicoper with a disabled rudder propeller and will cause imminent danger of crash because it causes the copter to spin.

I am a private pilot and especially in single-engine airplanes like Cessna 182 the torque of the propeller causes significant loss of authority on the yoke and has to be dealt with. We need to control the roll and yaw (rotation of the plane on the horizontal plane about the Z-axis) it causes with the ailerons combined with the rudder. Thi procedure is different for each airplane and the pilot must follow the manufacturer's instructions. Here is a link to torque reaction.

[source](https://www.flightliteracy.com/basic-propeller-principles-part-two/)

.

[image: torque reaction]

## Edit

after some comments I googled specifically jet engines' torque. and summing up the statement the answer is yes they do create torque.

unless in exceptional cases like in vertical lifiting Harrier fighter jet were there is no stream of air at take off to counter the torqu they have added a fan on the front, turning the opposite direction of the jet engine with revrse torque to cancel the engine torque.

Comment: The question is about a turboprop. Totally different. The conrods create all the engine mount torque in an ICE. Jets don't have those. Residual torque in jet mounts is optional. It is a design choice. An alternative is to accept swirl in the jet exhaust. The real issue here is the gearbox arrangement, which the OP hasn't described.

Comment: @PhilSweet What you say is true in theory, but the only "jet engine" design I know where *all* the mechanical torque is reacted by aerodynamic torque and none appears at the engine mounts is this one, designed a few thousand years ago: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeolipile. The gearbox is irrelevant, except for semantic arguments about which side the boundary between the "engine" and "airframe" it is on.

Comment: @alephzero The gearbox is relevant. More than 90 percent of the mounting torque will be due to the reduction gears. There aren't any options here. A 15:1 gearbox is going to put 14 times the input torque onto the mounts no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

The engine mount (connection) is responsible for the maximum horizontal force on the plane including the effect of the thrust, and its weight.

[image]

**ADD:**

The pictures below show how the engine is attached (mounted) to the pylon, which is attached to the wing. The simple connections (19a & 19b) make me hesitate to think they can resist the torque (rotated about the axis of travel). Or maybe the torque is rather small.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So where is the torque reaction on your diagram? Or not sure where it goes :)

Comment: I don't know the engine, but after a few readings, it goes like the gas pushes the pistons, which moves the crankcase that connects and rotates the flywheel in a CW or CCW direction to produce the torque in the shaft housing/transmission. The engine will experience torque if the rotation is suddenly reversed, as the designed rotation can either be CW or CCW.

Comment: There is no reaction in the engine for the torque it produced. The ultimate reaction is, for cars, at the contact of the tire and the road, for an airplane in the air, it is the thrust.

Comment: @r13, I want to agree with what you are saying since I believe the same. But in reality and according to some other experts, there is some torque production at the engine casing itself which makes the engine mount to experience a reaction torque. Doesn't make sense near me as well, but apparently this is true somehow lol

Comment: @RameezUlHaq do the drill experiment - you will understand then.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq Thanks for been your moral support, I don't have doubt as I don't have the background on machines. However, imaging holding a rotation rod by hands, unless squeeze the rod tight to stop the rotation, what is the force on the hands? But, no doubt, there is a reaction to the component that holds the force/energy source that causes the rod to rotate. For a car engine, the mounting should consider the dynamic force of the cylinder housing, rather than the torque it produced.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq Here is an interesting video to watch and think about. https://youtu.be/zA_19bHxEYg

Comment: @r13 You show a picture of a turboprop (which is what the OP asked about) and then talk about "pistons" in a comment.  Turboprops don't have pistons!

Comment: @r13 "There is no reaction in the engine for the torque it produced." If that was true (which is isn't), why do helicopters have a separate tail rotor to balance the engine torque transmitted to the airframe?

Comment: @alephzero See Phil Sweet's comment (under NMech's answer). I don't know about helicopters (traditional and vertical lift). How about the washing machine?! :)

Comment: @alephzero For your information and for the benefit of CE, here is something to think about - if the support of the modern engine needs to be designed for the power/torque it produces, most of the powerplants equipped with turbines couldn't be built, though there are torques to be considered, those torques are mainly induced by the imbalance of other loads with respect to the drive shaft axis and mass center of the unit.